# How jQuery .inArray() works

Tags: jquery

Short query is, in below piece of code why it's not printing **found?**

```
var products = [];
products.push("ABC", "XYZ");
var compareProducts = ["ABC","XYZ"];

console.log(products)


  if($.inArray(products, compareProducts) > -1)
    {
    alert("found"); 
  }
  else{
    alert("not found");
  }
```

Comment: What are u trying to do. The syntax is `$.inArray(needle, haystack);` You are providing both paramerters as array.

Comment: First parameter is supposed to be a value not the array itself.. go thorugh the [.inArray API](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: got it guys my bad... Thanks for help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation,

> The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.

That's exactly how it works:

```
inArray: function( elem, arr, i ) {
    return arr == null ? -1 : indexOf.call( arr, elem, i );
}
```

It finds the occurcence of your `elem` in `arr`. It does not find the occurence of obejcts of an array in another array.

If you want to check that all items in `products` exist in `compareProducts`, you may iterate over the array or use `Array.prototype.every`:

```
var products = [];
products.push("ABC", "XYZ");

var compareProducts = ["ABC","XYZ"];

if (products.every(function(x) { return $.inArray(x, compareProducts) > -1; }))
{
    alert("found"); 
} else {
    alert("not found");
}
```

Comment: The `products.every` will only determine if all `products` are in `compareProducts`.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters to the inArray function is `(String, Array)` and not `(Array, Array)` in your case. Iterate over products and match each value using `inArray`

Comment: Beat me to it. Try: `if($.inArray(products[0], compareProducts) > -1)`

Answer (score 0):

`inArray` is used to find the index of any `single value`, `not multiple values` .
you are searching for an array in an array which is not meant for `inArray`.